# You cannot delete vault '' because it contains registered servers

Tags: azure-devops

I am getting the following error

> You cannot delete vault BuildServerBackup because it contains registered servers. Delete the servers and the restore points for the server data, and then delete the vault."

But when i click the `Register` tab this is what it says

> You haven't registered any servers yet. To get started, download the appropriate agent and use it to register your server with the recovery service."

So how do i find out and delete all the associated server ?

Comment: Can you describe where you are seeing this message, and on what product and technologies?

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the registered Windows server before you can delete the backup vault. Here are the instructions to delete registered server(s)

1. Goto Azure Portal and select your backup vault
2. Select "Registered Items" from top menu Select the server type.
3. In the Drop down item next to the word  `TYPE` Select Windows Server for Windows client machines and click the tick button on the right
4. Select the server and click Delete button in the bottom action bar.

[image: Deleting Registered Servers for Azure backup vault]

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This was helpful.  The bad UI meant I didn't ever figure out you had to confirm the change in selection with the tick on the right before you could see the 'hidden' servers.